# OpenFileDialog filename serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

In writing a program where I need to serialize an *AppSettings* object which consists of several properties including one that will be used to store a last used filename, I have found that the FileName property is placed into my object (by assignment) but it does not serialize to the xml file.  No exceptions are thrown and no data is written.

But conversely, if I programmtically modify the object

```
tc.TheDataFile = "c:\\Documents And Settings\\SomeUser\\Sample\\a test file.txt";
```

instead of

```
tc.TheDataFile = theDialog.FileName;
```

That will work.  Can someone please provide some insight with regard to what I am missing?

Here is a simple version of the program that is directly related to the problem.

The test class which will theoretically hold the AppSettings ---

```
[Serializable()]
public class TestClass
{
    private string m_TheDataFile;
    private bool m_UseLastKnownDataFile = true;


    public bool UseLastKnownDataFile
    {
        get
        {
            return m_UseLastKnownDataFile;
        }
        set
        {
            m_UseLastKnownDataFile = value;
        }
    }

    public string TheDataFile
    {
        get
        {
            return m_TheDataFile;
        }
        set
        {
            m_TheDataFile = value;
        }
    }
}

public class TestClassHelper
{
    public static TestClass Load()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
        TestClass retVal;
        TextReader reader = null;
        bool fileNotFound = false; ;

        try
        {
            reader = new StreamReader("TestClassConfig.xml");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            fileNotFound = true;
        }

        if (fileNotFound)
        {
            retVal = new TestClass();
        }
        else
        {
            retVal = (TestClass)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
        }

        return retVal;
    }

    public static void Save(TestClass settings)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
        TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("TestClassConfig.xml");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, settings);
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

And here is the form which will prompt the user for a filename.  In this test, there is a form with one button.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    TestClass tc = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tc = TestClassHelper.Load();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog theDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        string fileName = string.Empty;

        theDialog.CheckFileExists = true;
        theDialog.CheckPathExists = true;
        theDialog.Multiselect = false;
        theDialog.FileName = string.Empty;


        if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tc.TheDataFile = theDialog.FileName;
        }
        else
        {
            tc.TheDataFile = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestClassHelper.Save(tc);
    }
}
```

Edit To Add: 
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Team Edition w/Dot Net 2.0.50727 SP1, with no options to upgrade the development environment.

Solution
I'm not exactly sure why this happens, but the OpenFileDialog control must change the current operating directory of the program.  When the object is deserialized to the xml file, it no longer writes where it originally opened.  Rather it is created in the *new* directory.

I corrected the problem by making the XML read and write location more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting `tc.TheDataFile = fileName;` after the `if` block, but you *never assign anything to `fileName`* except when you initialize it to `string.Empty`.  One fix would be:

```
    if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileName = theDialog.FileName;
    }

    // record last used data file
    tc.TheDataFile = fileName;
```

or just

```
    if (theDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        tc.TheDataFile = theDialog.FileName;
    }
```

Note that running your test in the debugger and "watch"ing the variables would have made the problem fairly easy to spot.

Comment: Sorry.  That line of code should have been omitted.  It would definitely cause a problem, but that was not THE problem.  Would you mind trying it again without that line of code?

Comment: @user3108410 I can't debug your code.  Have you run it in the debugger line-by-line to see what the issue may be?

Comment: Yes. And I have followed the execution of code all the way to the line of code in the "Save" method which Serializes the data --- serializer.Serialize(writer, settings);  and the filename value is present in the "settings" variable.  Yet the xml file is not modified.